# How to get IP address

Tags: vb5

In VB5, how do I get the IP address of the user?  There is a property called remotehostIP, and it looks like this might be the way, but I do not know how to use it!
Thanks.

Comment: Is this server side VB via ASP?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hkDD03yeLnU

Comment: Have you tried using the WshNetwork object?